# Dealing with rounding errors in SAS

Tags: sql, database, sas, rounding, proc

I'm working on a large data application and have run into a rounding error that I can't seem to fix. The code is basically like this:

```
proc sql;
select round(amount,.01) - round(amount * (percentage/100),.01) as amount
from data;
quit;
```

I've tried various methods of fixing, but all seem to lead to other rounding errors in the other direction cropping up. For the row that produces the error amount = 56.45 and percentage = 10. I get the result equal to 50.80 and am hoping for the result to equal 50.81. I cannot accept the rounding error as there is a separate process that reverses the transactions that does not have a rounding error and in the end the reversals plus the part producing the rounding error must add up to zero.

Code I've tried:

```
select round((((100-percentage)/100)*amount), .01)
select round(amount,.01) - round(amount * (percentage/100),.001) as amount
```

the second of which fixes the issue but creates three rounding errors in the other direction.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include some sample data including the expected output? Is this Canadian data or American? There's some weird rounding rules with cash payments in Canada because we dropped the penny.

Comment: Data is American. All numeric values are floating points in SAS which is what makes it hard to correct. In the example above, the reason for the rounding error is .9 * 56.45 = 50.805. There is some imprecision in the floating point multiplication which leads to 50.805 actually being slightly less than that and the value being rounded down when doing a round to the second decimal. Other values are similar but rounded correctly because they don't hit that sweet spot that causes the error.

Comment: there is a separate related row where percentage = 10 and amount = 56.45. This equals 5.64. 5.64+50.80 = 56.44 which does not equal the original total of 56.45 and won't survive an audit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing your datatypes, I can't say for certain, but here are some changes that should help resolve your issue:

1. Make sure you are working with decimal data types, not floats.
2. Round *after* you finish the math.  You are rounding each step of your calculation in two of your code snippets, which is likely to produce incorrect results.
3. Be very careful with your order of operations/parentheses.  For example, `100-percentage/100` evaluates to `100-10/100` = `100-0.1` = `99.9`, which I think is not what you want.  Similarly, you have one more close parenthesis than open on that line.

Comment: Rounding after finishing the math worked. Thank you.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!  If you found this answer helpful in resolving your problem, you might want to consider accepting it so that the question is marked as answered.